# Unitary operator between two orthonormal basis'

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

today I started studying the topic of Hilbert spaces. I was solving a problem concerning unitary operators and I got stuck with one of the subquestions which are stated as follows: Imagine we have two Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$ whose orthonormal basis are given by $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ respectively. I had to show that there exists a unique unitary operator $U: H \rightarrow K$ such that
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: U(e_n) = f_n$$
I know a unitary operator is a bijective linear function for which it holds that
$$\forall x,y \in H: \quad \langle U(x),U(y)\rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$$
However, I am completely stuck and do not know how to start solving this problem. I think I, first of all, have to show that such a unitary operator does exist and after that prove that it is unique. Does anyone have a tip to start solving this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: Do you know that any $x \in H$ has an exapnsion of the type $\sum a_n e_n$? What is an obvious defintion of $Ux$?

Comment: that $U(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nf_n$ maybe?

Comment: That is right. Now you just need some routine verifications.

Comment: Ok thank you but I've got one more question, so since the $x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_ne_n$ is an infinite sum and we want to have that $U(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nf_n$ we make the calculation that $U(x) = U(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_ne_n) = U(\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n a_ne_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_nf_n$. Now I don't know why we can put the limit outside of n and are we certain that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_nf_n$ converges?

Comment: Ok i have proven the convergence however the part where I exchange U and the limit remains unclear why this can be done. I tried to proof that U is continuous but this is not working out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator you are looking for satisfies
$$
U(e_n)=f_n, \quad n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
You have to prove that such correspondence uniquely specifies $U$ and that such a $U$ is unitary. Since any $x\in H$ can expanded as
$$
x=\sum_n x_n e_n
$$
and $U$ is linear, the action of $U$ is uniquely specified for any $x\in H$ by
$$
U(x)=\sum_n x_n U (e_n)=\sum_n x_n f_n\in K.
$$
Moreover, $U^{-1}$ exists and it is clearly uniquely specified by the correspondence
$$
U^{-1}(f_n)=e_n.
$$
In order to prove unitary, it remains to check $U$ preserves inner products. Expanding $x,y\in H$ as
$$
x=\sum_n x_n e_n, \quad y=\sum_n y_n e_n
$$
we have
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{n,m} x_n y_m \langle e_n, e_m\rangle= \sum_{n} x_n y_n.
$$
where the orthonormality of the basis has been used. Now, it is straightforward to check that
$$
\langle U(x),U(y)\rangle=\sum_{n,m} x_n y_n.
$$
Therefore $U$ is an isometric and invertible operator, so it is a unitary operator.